# How to re-load a hidden form

Tags: vb.net

I have a program with 3 forms.  Each form with the exception of the main has a "Back" button.
Form 3 Back button code is:

```
me.hide
form2.show
```

However when I make my changes on form2 and hit "next"

Code for next:

```
Me.hide
form3.show
```

The form appears, but does not re-run the form "load" code

What am I missing?

Comment: From MSDN: `[Form Load event] Occurs before a form is displayed for the first time.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form load event is fired before a form is displayed for the first time.  To invoke initialization code upon request:

```
Private Sub Form_Load(...)
    ' one time only code here

    FormSetup               ' link to everytime code

End Sub

Friend Sub FormSetup        
    ' code to run each time it shows

End Sub
```

Then to call it:

```
frm.FormSetup
frm.Show
```

Comment: Am i calling "form3.formsetup" then form3.show on form 2?

Comment: use the form reference for the form you are about to show.  presumably there is a similar issue if you go back to form2

Comment: This doesn't work because the next button, on form 2 saves info to an xml file, and the form load (now formsetup called from the button click) causes a conflict.  says xml file is in use.

Comment: but wouldnt you get that if form load ran a second time?  There is always one time only stuff - that is why I have it split into `one time only` and `each time it loads`.  the latter is typically just updating display elements.  whatever you **do** want to happen everytime goes in the new FormSetup procedure